# Why did I fail to index to Algolia?

Tags: gatsby, algolia

I am following the [gatsby tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-search-with-algolia/) for installing algolia. After doing `gatsby build` I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'addObjects' of undefined
```

My `src/utils/algolia.js` file

```
  const postQuery = `{
    posts: allMarkdownRemark(
      filter: { fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/content/" } }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          objectID: id
          frontmatter {
            title
            date(formatString: "DD MMMM, YYYY")
          }
          excerpt(pruneLength: 5000)
        }
      }
    }
  }`

  const flatten = arr =>
    arr.map(({ node: { frontmatter, ...rest } }) => ({
      ...frontmatter,
      ...rest,
    }))
  const settings = { attributesToSnippet: [`excerpt:20`] }

  const queries = [
    {
      query: postQuery,
      transformer: ({ data }) => flatten(data.posts.edges),
      indexName: `Posts`,
      settings,
    },
  ]

  module.exports = queries
```

I followed the basic tutorial with minimal customization. What am I doing wrong?

My [github](https://github.com/develijahlee/yonseiuicscribe)

Comment: On GitHub the project doesn't contain the Algolia plugin. Could you add the configuration for Gatsby? It would help to better understand where the problem comes from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens when the index you specified doesn't exist.

In your case the code you posted specifies to use an index called `Posts`, e.g.:

```
indexName: `Posts`,
```

The gatsby algolia plugin will try to find this index and push to it. If it doesn't exist, it fails with this rather cryptic error.

In order to fix it, log into your Algolia dashboard and create an index with that name.

Comment: I opened a pull request with a fix (better error message) here: https://github.com/algolia/gatsby-plugin-algolia/pull/60

Comment: It's not true. By default Algolia creates the index if it doesn't exist already. https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/getting-started/instantiate-client-index/#init-index

Comment: @SamuelVaillant it didn't for me. I couldn't get the plugin to work at all w/o creating an index first.

Comment: You're right about the plugin but not about Algolia. Yes the plugin doesn't work without the index already created but it's the case with Algolia. The issue is inside the plugin not with Algolia.

Comment: Hi Joscha, I was wondering if you could help me with a similar algolia question as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62677407/algolia-fails-to-index-on-netlify-deploy