# Algolia fails to index on netlify deploy

Tags: gatsby, algolia, netlify

On netlify I get the following error when deploying

```
10:12:15 PM: Algolia: 1 queries to index
10:12:16 PM: Algolia: query 0: executing query
10:12:16 PM: Algolia: query 0: graphql resulted in 230 records
10:12:16 PM: Algolia: query 0: splitting in 1 jobs
10:12:16 PM: error failed to index to Algolia
10:12:16 PM: 
10:12:16 PM: 
10:12:16 PM:   TypeError: Cannot read property 'addObjects' of undefined
10:12:16 PM:   
10:12:16 PM:   - gatsby-node.js:161 
10:12:16 PM:     [repo]/[gatsby-plugin-algolia]/gatsby-node.js:161:43
10:12:16 PM:   
10:12:16 PM:   - Array.map
10:12:16 PM:   
10:12:16 PM:   - gatsby-node.js:160 doQuery
10:12:16 PM:     [repo]/[gatsby-plugin-algolia]/gatsby-node.js:160:30
10:12:16 PM:   
10:12:16 PM:   - async Promise.all
10:12:16 PM:   
10:12:16 PM:   - gatsby-node.js:187 async Object.exports.onPostBuild
10:12:16 PM:     [repo]/[gatsby-plugin-algolia]/gatsby-node.js:187:5
10:12:16 PM:   
10:12:16 PM: 
10:12:16 PM: not finished onPostBuild - 1.338s
```

But when I do `gatsby build` I get the following

```
Algolia: 1 queries to index
Algolia: query 0: executing query
Algolia: query 0: graphql resulted in 230 records
Algolia: query 0: splitting in 1 jobs
Algolia: query 0: moving copied index to main index
⠼ onPostBuild
info Generated public/sw.js, which will precache 9 files, totaling 446903 bytes.
The following pages will be precached:
/offline-plugin-app-shell-fallback/index.html
success onPostBuild - 6.228s
```

After doing `gatsby serve` I see that I can see my posts results fine as I type through queries in the searchbar. However, whenever I click on a post, I get linked to a strange root such as `0.0.7.226`/post-name.

I recently uninstalled all node modules and reinstalled to make sure my dependencies are up to date. What is getting me this error?

My [github](https://github.com/uicscribe/yonseiuicscribe)

Comment: Very strange. Have you configured GATSBY_ALGOLIA_APP_ID, GATSBY_ALGOLIA_SEARCH_KEY and ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY correctly as environment variables in Netlify?

Comment: Thank you that solved the netlify error as I did not update the env variables on netlify. However the 0.0.7.226/post-name url persists as can be seen here https://yonseiuicscribe-master.netlify.app/search/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the env variables on netlify to successfully deploy the website but the 0.0.7.226/post-name url persists

Comment: I'd suggest you create a new question for this. You'd also need to post the code that renders the links to the post.